# How can I add an additional object to the results of a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have the following code that I need to add an additonal object to after the results have been retrieved from the databse. Any Ideas on how I might to this ?

```
   public IEnumerable<ProdPriceDisplay> GetShopProductsPrices()
{

    //ProdPriceDisplay ProdPrice = new ProdPriceDisplay();
    var Products = from shop in db.SHOPs
                   select new ProdPriceDisplay
                   {
                       ProdPrice = shop.S_NAME + " - £" + shop.S_PRICE
                   };

    // *** Want to add something like this:-

    //  Products.Add new ProdPriceDisplay { ProdPrice = "some additional text"; }

    return Products;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx):

```
public IEnumerable<ProdPriceDisplay> GetShopProductsPrices()
{
    var products = from shop in db.SHOPs
                   select new ProdPriceDisplay
                   {
                       ProdPrice = shop.S_NAME + " - £" + shop.S_PRICE
                   };

    return products.AsEnumerable()
                   .Concat(new [] { new ProdPriceDisplay 
                           { ProdPrice = "some additional text"; });
}
```

The benefit of this over converting to a list is that the results are still streamed, so you don't end up taking a complete copy of the data.

EDIT: You could use [`Enumerable.Repeat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899.aspx) `(new ProdPriceDisplay { ... }, 1)` instead of the array if you wanted to - but there's not a lot of benefit.

EDIT: I've added the call to [`AsEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx) which basically says, "At this point, we don't want to do the rest of the operations in the database - make them local."

Answer (score 0):

That could be a solution;

```
var productsAsList = Products.ToList();
productsAsList.Add(new ProdPriceDisplay { ProdPrice = "some additional text"; });

return productsAsList; // As your return type is IEnumarable, that won't be a problem;
```

Comment: Yes this is a solution but I recommend the Jon's as he mentioned its benefits.